# Swift WebView with didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, webview

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let row = indexPath.row
    println(row)
    let section = indexPath.section
    println(section)

    let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Smokes")
    self.showViewController(vc as! UIViewController, sender: vc)

    if (section == 0 && row == 0){
            let requestURL = NSURL(string: URLDustCTRampFromALong)
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
            WebView.loadRequest(request)
            }
```

It crashes once I click on the table. I want to make a table and when you click on a row it opens on the same WebView, but with different URL. Any ideas?

P.S. I'm a beginner

Comment: Could you add the error you receive when you crash to your question? It makes it easier to zoom in on where things went wrong. One idea though. You say `self.showViewController(vc as! UIViewController, sender:vc)`. I'm not sure that the sender should be vc. Try with self instead perhaps?

Comment: 0x10d484823 <+1491>: callq  0x10d48efd6               ; symbol stub for: function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()
    0x10d484828 <+1496>: movq   -0x110(%rbp), %rax

Comment: This looks like the assembler code that was running when the exception occurred. But can you see any output in the console in the bottom of Xcode? Otherwise. Try to comment out lines until you isolate the line that's causing the crash. Just so we can get an idea about what's happening :-)